# Node.js doesn't serve page on proxy pass from apache

Tags: javascript, websocket, server

I've found similar questions on Stack and other forums but no working answers.

I have a node.js chat server running on port 3000 of my local machine, and an Apache server running on port 80. They both work as expected: browsing to localhost gives me Apache, and localhost:3000 gives me the node app. However, when I set up a `ProxyPass` directive to make the nodejs app accessible from `localhost/node`, like this...

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyRequests Off
ServerName localhost
ProxyPass /node http://localhost:3000/
ProxyPassReverse /node http://localhost:3000/
</VirtualHost>
```

... the page loads, but the server isn't processing the page. It renders, but node doesn't work.

Notably, the following configuration allows me to access the node server on port 80 for *all* traffic, but isn't what I want to achieve.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyRequests Off
ServerName localhost
ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: What does "It renders but node doesn't work" mean? If requesting `http://localhost/node` gets a page to render, then where does that page come from if it isn't from node?

Comment: Welcome to the site! This may be a valuable question, but you will probably need to provide more specific and clear information to get helpful answers. Good luck!

Comment: @quentin  The page loads with all formatting (css, etc), however, no information from the node server is being returned.... like the date.  When the page connects to the node server, node SHOULD return a welcome message.  That message and connectivity isn't happening.

Comment: @Vbudo — "When the page connects to the node server" — What does this mean? Aren't you connecting to the node server when you request `/node`? Which you said gives you an HTML document? And then again when you get the CSS?

Comment: The page is probably goning through the apache web server... nodejs isn't connecting.  There isn't any communication with the node server.